# TypeError: Missing parameter name at 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa

I am building a simple server on Javascript using node.js platform. I have 2 files which are called server.js and db.js. I found a weird error while testing server.js. Below you'll find the 3 files in question. Any and all answers are greatly appreciated!

[Error on node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9WuR.png)

```
C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\path-to-regexp\dist\index.js:48
                throw new TypeError("Missing parameter name at " + i);
                ^

TypeError: Missing parameter name at 14
    at lexer (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\path-to-regexp\dist\index.js:48:23)
    at parse (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\path-to-regexp\dist\index.js:98:18)
    at stringToRegexp (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\path-to-regexp\dist\index.js:331:27)
    at pathToRegexp (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\path-to-regexp\dist\index.js:405:12)
    at new Layer (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\@koa\router\lib\layer.js:43:17)
    at Router.register (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\@koa\router\lib\router.js:570:17)
    at Router.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\node_modules\@koa\router\lib\router.js:200:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Charu Nasa\Finsectrade\backend\server.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

*Code file:*

**Server.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa');

const Router = require('@koa/router');

const cors = require('@koa/cors');

const ethers = require('ethers');

const Paymentframework = require('../build/contracts/Paymentframework.json');

const {Payment} = require('./db.js');

const app = new Koa();

const router = new Router();

router.get('/api/getpayID/: AssetID', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.body = 'goldasset'; 
});

app
 .use(cors())
 .use(router.routes())
 .use(router.allowedMethods());

 app.listen (4000, () =>{
    console.log('Server running on port 4000');
 });
```

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(
'your connection string', 
'mongodb+srv://abcd:<abcd1234>@finsectrade.di8n0.mongodb.net/<finsectrade >?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
);

const paymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    AssetID: String,
paid: Boolean}
);

const Payment = mongoose.model('Payment', paymentSchema);

 module.exports = {
    Payment
 };
```

Comment: it appears Koa/router is broken. You should uninstall that package, delete your package-lock.json file, delete your node_modules folder and run `nom I`. This _might_ fix it. But, during the install you must make note of any installation errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried but I am still getting the same error